# Initializing a UITableView with "inserted" Rows

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, insert

I've got a UITableView that I want to insert and delete rows in.

If I have an array of 10 values and start with the tableview including all rows, the table displays fine.  Then if I want to filter out everything except [0, 1, 5].  I then go through the process of deleting rows at index paths: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9] and the returned number of rows is 3.  I don't have to change my cell rendering code, it displays rows: [0, 1, 5].

However, if after having filtered everything, I want to come back to this table and load from persistence the table with rows [0, 1, 5], I'm having trouble.  The table loads with number of rows: 3 and renders cells: [0, 1, 2].

I've tried initializing the table in viewDidLoad with 0 rows and then in viewDidAppear calling insertRows:[0, 1, 5] - but this throws an exception:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:909
```

And I've verified that in viewDidLoad, the number of rows is printing 0, and just before this error is thrown, the number of rows printed is 3.

EDIT
If I insert instead [0, 1, 2] - it works... but again... I ultimately need [0, 1, 5] showing up.

```
 - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated
 {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSArray *initializing_indeces = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0]];
    [self.userDataTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:initializing_indeces withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

```
- (int) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Using different booleans, but the gist:
    if (viewDidLoad)
        return 0;
    if (viewDidAppear || filtered)
        return 3;
    if (expanded)
        return 10;
}
```

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    }


    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: put relavent code here :)

Comment: Ok see these link & check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241625/getting-an-assertion-failure-error & also this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134841/assertion-failure-in-uitableview-endcellanimationswithcontext

Comment: In numberOfRowsInSection your should give 10 row .. And complite any oparation write [tableView reloadData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to keep track of the mapping myself:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    }


    int row = indexPath.row;
    if (filtered) {
        // Translate 0 - 0
        // Translate 1 - 1
        // Translate 2 - 5
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", row]];

    return cell;
}
```

I ended up using an NSMutableArray that, when filtered, becomes [0, 1, 5] so accessing the index of that array, indexPath.row of 2 returns 5.

Answer (score 1):

@Fish stix

> [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString
> stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row]];

this method in your code clearly states that, text will be NSString with indexPath.row's value. Now when you are deleting your rows and data source, from `10 = [0, 1, 5] + [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]` to `3 = [0, 1, 5]`. Your data source has been reduced to an array of count 3. Hence you will get three rows only as returned bby `numberOfRowsInSection` method. The three rows will have these indexPath.row's `0, 1, 2`. And hence you are getting `0,1 ,2` instead of `0, 1 ,5`.

if you print the indexPath, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (after filtering) you will see them as [0, 0] [0, 1] [0, 2] meaning section 0, and row number 0, 1, 2 respectively. And hence your result

> As in to get your desired result. do this. take a property @property
> (retain, nonAtomic) NSArray *dataArray;
>
> in **viewDidLoad**:
> self.dataArray = [NSArray
> arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",
> nil];
>
> in **numberOfRowsInSection**
> return [array count];
>
> and in **cellForRow** [cell.textLabel setText:[self.dataArray
> objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
>
> Now just change the dataSource (i mean dataArray) to filtered or
> expanded state) in **viewWillAppear** or wherever you want and reload
> the table data using [self.tableView reloadData];

Hope I am clear. Cheers, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

First in your case `numberOfRowsInSection` return `NSInteger` not `int`, so please change it

I don't Exactly what is The resone.
I assume That Problem  must be connected to this part in your code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Generally  you are making a mistake in one of these data source methods. 
May be it's impossible to say what exactly is wrong but  it could be something like: You are telling the table view in `thenumberOfRowsInSection`  (*in your case 10* )and in      `thecellForRowAtIndexPath` you then only handle ***10 - 1*** rows for example.
If you show us your implementation of your data source it would be much easier to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

For each time inserting you need to reload the tableview  using `[tableView realodData]`